# Flutter run project stuck when xcrun xcodebuild with mac M1

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, visual-studio-code

this past days, run my flutter project has been a big mess.

In fact, for no reason, my project run and all is under control and when I run again, my command is stuck when flutter run use xcrun xcodebuild command.

I think it is link to my xcode issue that I encounter sometimes. The issue with Xcode is that sometimes I can't open the project because it make crash the software (Xcode), that make an infinite loading.

I'm gonna give what I can to help you guys !

Here is my flutter doctor :

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on macOS 12.2.1 21D62 darwin-arm, locale
    fr-FR)
    • Flutter version 2.10.3 at /Users/lucas/Development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 7e9793dee1 (5 days ago), 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600
    • Engine revision bd539267b4
    • Dart version 2.16.1
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0-rc4)
    • Android SDK at /Users/lucas/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0-rc4
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.65.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.36.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone 13 (mobile) • 6B22E1B8-B38C-4342-AAFF-163495D302EE • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-2 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)       • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 99.0.4844.51

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Here is the last lines where my flutter run -v is stuck :

```
[  +18 ms] executing: [/Users/lucas/Desktop/Grafen_it/Produits/Clients/Velyvelo/Mobile/VelyVelo/ios/]
/usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun xcodebuild -list
[  +33 ms] <- compile
file:///Users/lucas/Desktop/Grafen_it/Produits/Clients/Velyvelo/Mobile/VelyVelo/.dart_tool/flutter_build/g
enerated_main.dart
```

I've try to rebuild, close and open and also reload my computer (Mac M1 Monterey v12.2.1: )

And I'm trying to run on ios emulator !

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Can you open the iOs folder in xcode and run it in xcode, then feedback me what is the returned error.